# Remove element in strings arraylist java

Tags: java, android

Hi am new in using Java and I just placed a list of strings in an array list of which I would like to remove certain elements in each of the strings below

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();


data.add( "ksh10,000"); 
data.add( "ksh20,000");  
data.add( "ksh30,000");
data.add( "ksh40,000");
data.add( "ksh50,000');
```

so I would like to remove the "ksh" and the comma in between the strings so as to get an out put like

```
10000,20000,30000,40000,50000
```

what i tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.lenght(); i++ ) {
    data.set(i, data.get(i).replace("ksh", ""));
    data.set(i, data.get(i).replace(",",""));
}
```

.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How did you try?post that too

Comment: Remember String is immutable, using `String.replace` will only return a new string instead of replace the old string. Hope this will help you

Comment: We need more code. Show us what you have tried. How are data and money related in your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the values put into data, loop through each element and use the `replace` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++ ) {
    data.set(i, data.get(i).replace("ksh", ""));
    data.set(i, data.get(i).replace(",",""));
}
```

This replaces "ksh" strings and commas with an empty string. as Snoob said, `replace()` only returns the new String, because Strings are immutable.

Comment: Thanks Nordii this worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

This is a great change to use the `Stream` API.  I'm going to leave one piece of the implementation up to you as an exercise.

```
import java.util.stream.*;

class Solution { 

String generateOutput (ArrayList<String> inputValues) { 
  return data.stream()
             .map(this::scrubValue)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}

String scrubValue (String input) {
  // you'll need to write code here that takes an input like "ksh10,000" and returns "10000"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add( "ksh10,000");
    list.add( "ksh20,000"); 
    list.add( "ksh30,000"); 
    list.add( "ksh40,000"); 
    list.add( "ksh50,000"); 
    printStrings(list);

    ArrayList<String> newList = editList(list);
    printStrings(newList);

}

public static ArrayList<String> editList(ArrayList<String> list){
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String str : list) {
        String temp = "";
        for(char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
                temp += c;
        }
        newList.add(temp);
    }

    return newList;
}

public static void printStrings(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(String str : list){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

}
```

The best way to do this (if you don't know the exact structure of the string) is to check if a character is a digit and if so add it to the string, loop this for every string in the list and return a new list which contains the edited version of the strings in the first list.

Comment: `ArrayList` is inherited from `AbstractCollection` which has already implemented `toString` method, you can just use System.out.println(list).

Comment: It's like 3 AM where I am...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would only like to extract numbers from the ArrayList of String. so we can use a regex such as [^0-9] to remove all non-digits like below.

```
String number = stringData.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

here stringData is the string from which you want to extract only numbers.
Below is the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
    data.set(i, data.get(i).replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    }
```

Hope it helps.